# Boostrap nav float on top of google map

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I have the bootstrap nav bar float on top of the google map?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        getLocation(); 
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

      function getLocation(){
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
        } else {
          // default location
        }
      }

      function success(position){
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

        var mapOptions = {
          center: latlng,
          zoom: 12
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }

      function error(msg){
        if (msg.code == 1) {
            //PERMISSION_DENIED 
        } else if (msg.code == 2) {
            //POSITION_UNAVAILABLE 
        } else {
        }   //TIMEOUT
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

    <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by float on the nav bar?

Comment: I mean the nav bar is on top of the map...

Comment: Position it absolutely? Although that will cover part of the maps functionality. http://jsbin.com/rawub/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Have you looked at creating Custom Controls for your map? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls

Answer (score 0):

If you mean float over the map, you can use Bootstrap's fixed top navbar..

http://www.bootply.com/124566

If you mean above the map vertically, you can use change the bottom margin on the navbar to 0..

http://www.bootply.com/124567